# Issue in team members access to azure devops project

Tags: azure-devops

I have added multiple team members to two different teams in Azure Devops project. But team members are not able to see organization, project and dashboards when they login to devops account?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the answer for my additional questinos.

1. To get an access to Devops project user must be added in the organization either as stakeholder or owner
2. Once they are owner or stakeholder they are able to access all the features.

Answer (score 0):

> team members are not able to see organization, project and dashboards

Users cannot see the organization, you can first check whether these users have been added to the organization in Users of Organization Settings.

[image]

Then you can check whether the user has the permission to access the project on the Manage user page.

[image]

Regarding that users cannot see the projects, you can check whether the “`View project-level information`” permission of the team is set to `Deny` in the Permissions of Projects Settings.

[image]

Regarding that the user cannot see the dashboard, there should be no permission to restrict it. All users in the project should be able to see the dashboard. Can you share the screenshots about this issue?

In addition, you can try to let users log in with incognito window to see if the problem exists. Check if your organization is connected to AAD.

Comment: Hi Lin, Thanks for your response. And it works as well. Is it required to add team member as a user, stakeholder in organization setting.

Comment: If the users are already  project team members, then the users should also already be in the Users of the organization settings.

Comment: Thanks again. I am able to add team members from Azure Active Directory they are not in Organization users list. One more observation even if they are team members I can remove them from Organization users list.